# woocomerce удалить товар ниже определнной стоимости

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

есть сайт с 40 тысяч товара, нужно удалить все товары стоимостью меньше 10 тысяч рублей. Помогите написать Sql запрос и запускать его по крону например ежедневно.

Comment: А вы какой запрос составляете?

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь то продукт записывается в таблицу `wp_post`. Соответственно `delete from wp_post where price < 1000000`. Точное название таблиц и полей уже проверьте сами в базе)

Comment: Спасибо, я пока только на фронте убрал add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'shop_only_instock_products', 10, 2 );
function shop_only_instock_products( $meta_query, $query ) {
    // In frontend only
    if( is_admin() ) return $meta_query;

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => '_price',
        'value'   => 9999,
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => '>'
    );
    return $meta_query;
}